# Insert values into using mysql and bootstrap?

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

> here is the bootstrap that i need to put into the database well im
>   new to bootstrap and mysql so i have no idea whether im doing it right
>   or wrong? i need some help badly. btw im making a simple online reservation system

```
 <div class = "panel-group" id = "Accordion">
        <div class = "panel panel-info">
            <div class = "panel-heading">
                <h4 class = "panel-title">
                    <a href="#res" ><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span> Reserve Now!</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
                <!-- Panel Body  -->
            <div class ="panel-body">
                    <div class = "row">


                    <form class="form-inline" role="form" action ="" method = "post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group" name = "from">
                            <div class="input-group-addon">FROM</div>
                             <select class="form-control input-sm">

                                <option selected disabled>Select Destination</option>
                                <option value="BCD">Bacolod</option>
                                <option value="BSO">Basco(Batanes)</option>
                                <option value="USU">Busuanga(Coron)</option>
                                <option value="BXU">Butuan</option>
                                <option value="CGY">Cagayan de Oro</option>
                                <option value="CYP">Calbayog</option>
                                <option value="CRM">Catarman</option>
                                <option value="BOR">Catician(Boracay)</option>
                                <option value="CEB">Cebu</option>
                                <option value="COT">Cotabato</option>
                                <option value="DVO">Davao</option>
                                <option value="DPL">Dipolog</option>
                                <option value="DGT">Dumaguete</option>
                                <option value="GES">General Santos</option>
                                <option value="ILO">Iloilo</option>
                                <option value="JOL">Jolo</option>
                                <option value="KLO">Kalibo</option>
                                <option value="LAO">Laoag</option>
                                <option value="LGP">Legazpi</option>
                                <option value="MNL">Manila</option>
                                <option value="MBT">Masbate</option>
                                <option value="NAG">Naga</option>
                                <option value="OZC'">Ozamiz</option>
                                <option value="PPS">Puerto Princesa</option>
                                <option value="RXS">Roxas</option>
                                <option value="SUG'">Surigao</option>
                                <option value="TAC">Tacloban</option>
                                <option value="TAG">Tagbilaran(Bohol)</option>
                                <option value="TWT">Tawi Tawi</option>
                                <option value="TUG">Tuguegarao</option>
                                <option value="ZAM">Zamboanga</option>
            </select>
            </div>        
        </div>
```

and here is the mysql query that im tweaking right now . im using PDO. what should i do ? i edited this is now my full db.php its from my previous small blog post project.

```
<?php namespace ars\DB; // Global annoucement of location within the this page


$config = array(
    'username' =>'root',
    'password' => 'kel',
    'database' => 'ars'

);  // function can be reusable
    //function will be put to class namespace (real world)
function connect($config)
{   
    try {
        $conn = new \PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=' . 
                        $config['database'], 
                        $config['username'],
                        $config['password']);



        $conn->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        return $conn;
    } catch(exception $e ) {
        return false;
    }
}

    //helper function
function query($query, $bindings, $conn)
{
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute($bindings);

    return ( $stmt -> rowCount() > 0 ) ? $stmt : false;

}

   function get($tableName, $conn)
{   try{
        $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM $tableName ORDER BY id ");

            return( $result -> rowCount() > 0 )
            ? $result
            : false;
    }catch(Execption $e){
     return false;
    }
}
    // passing the id
function get_by_id($id, $conn)
{   
    // querying the id
    $query =  query(
        'SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1', 
        array('id' => $id), 
        $conn
    );

    if ($query) return  $query->fetchAll();
    // else

}
```

Comment: afaik an INSERT statement doesn't have an ORDER BY clause

Comment: you're not providing enough information for anyone to help you. Where and how are you reading the `POST` variables? where are you calling `get()` ?

Comment: ohh sorry man. im new to this site also well im just tweaking my previous small blog post project .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

there are many errors in this code. i cant help you with your problem but i can just point out some of these errors. first off,

- **there is no need for order by in insert**
- your function is get but you are inserting. (can i assume you are supposed to use select? if so, learn more about it. a little google search will save you).
- you can help us help you by showing your connect statement. (like
  mysqli_connect() function) note:dont use mysql_connect as it is
  depreciated.
- a note to point out is your 
  has no name attribute.  add a name="some_Select" in your select tag